# Going into a directory from Windows command prompt via Java

Tags: java, windows, cmd

Having a little bit of trouble with getting some commands to run in Windows command prompt via Java. I am looking to go into my system32 folder and run a certain file however it does not populate the command. Segment of the code below:

```
System.out.print("Press 1 for Normal or 2 for Keygen - " + client);
        String mode = input.nextLine().trim();
        if (mode.equals("1")) {
            String command = "cmd /c start cmd.exe";
             final String dosCommand = "cmd /c dir /s";
                final String location = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32"; 
            Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
             OutputStream out = child.getOutputStream();
                out.write(dosCommand.getBytes());
                out.flush();
                out.write(location.getBytes());
                out.close();
        } else if (mode.equals("2")) {

        } else {
            System.out.println("Option not recognised");
        }
```

Comment: This cod assumes that the `dir` command takes the directory to list from its standard input. It doesn't.

Comment: Tim's answer is the right way to do it.  But I think the specific problem with this code is that you aren't sending a space between the `/s` and the path, i.e., the command you're trying to run is `dir /sc:\windows\system32` instead of  `dir /s c:\windows\system32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be getting bogged down in your code.  Try using this instead:

```
System.out.print("Press 1 for Normal or 2 for Keygen - " + client);
String mode = input.nextLine().trim();

if (mode.equals("1")) {
    final String location = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32";
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start dir /p", null, new File(location));
} else if (mode.equals("2")) {
} else {
    System.out.println("Option not recognised");
}
```

Here is what happened when I ran this code snippet on my own computer:

[image]

If you want to run an actual program, you can just specify this inside the call to `Runtime.exec()`.  For example, suppose you want to launch a window and print out the Java version.  The command for this is `java -version` and you can use this line of code:

```
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd /k java -version", null, new File(loc));
```

Here, you will notice that I added an extra `cmd /k` to the command.  This will keep the window open even after the program has finished running.

Comment: This seems to definately be on the right track. say if i wanted to run a file called test.bat from the system32 folder, would it simply be adding the file name at the end of the location string?

Comment: @MubeenHussain I updated my answer to address your question.